# Angular 5 Combine or refactor multiple Subscribe calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I am using **Angular 5.2** in my web project. In one of the pages, i am using multiple subscribe calls to different webAPI methods. Although they are different and independent calls to bring different sets of data also.

But i am thinking is there a way to club/combine together the Subscribe calls in one syntax and makes the code look small and neat.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this._documentService.getTypes()
        .subscribe(px => {
            this._docTypeList = px;
        },

        error => {
           console.log("Grid Err:: " + error.message);
        }
        );


    this._documentService.getCategories()
        .subscribe(rx => {
            this._catList = rx;               
        },
        error => {
            console.log("Grid Err:: " + error.message);  }
        );
}
```

Is there a way i can refactor this code to make it short ?

Please suggest.

Comment: What should happen when they join?
Example if one has an error what should happen with the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `forkJoin` to combine multiple observables

```
forkJoin(this._documentService.getTypes(), this._documentService.getCategories() ) 
    .subscribe(rx => {
        this._docTypeList = rx[0] 
        this._catList = rx[1];               
    },
    error => {
        console.log("Grid Err:: " + error.message);  }
    );
```

Comment: let me quickly try.

Comment: Will forkJoin makes the multiple API calls together at the same time ?

Comment: yes. it will send multiple calls at once and wait until all the responses before subscribing

Comment: nice Sachila :-)

Comment: Lets say, if i have to do the error handling separately. Can we do with this syntax ?

Comment: if either one of those req get failed it comes under this error section only, you can handle it from server by sending a status to client and manage error